# Nelder Mead algorithm for constrained optimization?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, simplex

I have read that Nelder Mead algorithm is working for unconstrained optimization. 
http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nelder-Mead_algorithm
I think in Matlab Nelder Mead is used also for unconstrained optimization.
However, I am a little bit confused, since I found a Java API for optimization 
http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Minimisation.html
(Flanagan's Scientific Library)
that has a class that implements Nelder Mead simplex and allows for defining constraints and bounds.
So, is the version implemented in Flanagan's API a modified variation of the "classical" Nelder Mead algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the API is implementing a simple "soft" constraint system, where constraints are transformed into penalty functions which severely penalize regions outside the constraints. It's a cheap-and-cheerful way of adding constraints to an unconstrained solver, but there'll be a tradeoff between optimality, convergence, and the degree to which the constraints are satisfied.

Comment: ok, and do you know is there any scientific article that describes this adaptation of the original algorithm?

Comment: @Sorin I doubt there's one specifically for Nelder-Mead. Soft constraints are as old as dirt. Any good textbook on optimization will discuss them, though.

Comment: I was looking at the penalty weights proposed in the Flanagan's Scientific Library http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Minimisation.html#constraint but this appears to address only the individual simple constraints like x1>l or x1<u (with only 1 parameter bounded to a lower or upper bound). But I can't see any penalty system proposed for the constraints involving 2 or more parameters, such as x1<x2. The API says it supports this type of constraints "applied to a summation of some or all parameters" but I am wondering how it penalize it?

Comment: @Sorin COBYLA https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-cobyla.html#optimize-minimize-cobyla is a similar simplex-based optimizer that allows for general nonlinear constraints. COBYLA is a significant improvement on Nelder-Mead. You can learn more: Powell, M J D. A direct search optimization method that models the objective and constraint functions by linear interpolation